# creating a role with restricted permissions about countries in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-8

I'm new to drupal 8 dev and I have an issue creating a custom role with custom permissions.
Actually, I need to create a role based on admin permissions, but restricted to countries affected to this new role by the admin.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I've not misunderstood your question, but if you want users to have permissions based on the content itself, rather than by the content type. You should look into the permissions by term module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term

So if for example, you have a Drupal site where you have content tagged to countries, you could use this module to have a country-specific editor who can only edit the content tagged to their country.

Comment: Actually, I have different domains for my site, and what I want is to give permissions to a user from a country (country is a taxonomy) to edit, delete content only for the countries he will manage